# How do you get the text value from the DataInspector extension in GoJS?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am using the Data Inspector extension, as shown [here](https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.html):

- I would like to simply enter a number in one of the fields (ie
  maxLinks) to set the maximum number of allowed links from a selected
  node. How could I retrieve the inputs entered in one of the fields?
- Also, could the same be done with editable text fields (retrieve the
  text input)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the sample that you refer to, and in a typical usage such as in the sample Org Chart Editor, https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html, the DataInspector is showing properties of the selected node's data object in the model.  Some of those properties are editable.  When the user modifies the value and focus is lost, the inspector code commits a transaction to modify that data object's property value.

Because there is a **Binding** of some **GraphObject** property in the **Node** (or **Link**) template, modifying the data property by calling **Model.set** will update the corresponding GraphObject property, which will cause the diagram to update.

In your case you want a binding of **GraphObject.fromMaxLinks** from the "maxLinks" property on the node data object.  This is shown in the Node template, below.

Note how the **TextBlock.text** binding works so that the user can either edit the text in-place or edit it in the Inspector.

The complete sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GoJS Sample Using DataInspector</title>
<!-- Copyright 1998-2019 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../extensions/DataInspector.css" />
<script src="../extensions/DataInspector.js"></script>
<script id="code">
  function init() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          { "undoManager.isEnabled": true });

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape,
          { fill: "white", portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer" },
          // THIS IS THE CRUCIAL BINDING, from data.maxLinks to GraphObject.fromMaxLinks
          new go.Binding("fromMaxLinks", "maxLinks"),
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { margin: 8, editable: true },
          new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
      );

    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
      [
        { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
        { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange" },
        { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
        { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink" }
      ]);

    var inspector = new Inspector("myInspectorDiv", myDiagram,
      {
        properties:
        {
          key: { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent },
          maxLinks: { type: "number", defaultValue: Infinity, show: Inspector.showIfNode }
        }
      });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:600px"></div>
  <div id="myInspectorDiv" class="inspector"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Just one more question, how could I set the maxLinks so it applies for both ways regardless of the direction of the link (ie if set to 2, then only 2 link connections allowed on the node to and from)?

Comment: As is discussed at https://gojs.net/latest/intro/validation.html#MaxLinksProperties, you need to implement a **linkValidation** predicate: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/validation.html#GeneralLinkingValidation